# CSS/JS: Prevent jump when text is replaced with text of a different size

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$('button').click(function() {
 $('.parent .child').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
table {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.parent {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
.child.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button>toggle text</button>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>normal</td>
  <td>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child hidden">I'm long long long long long  long long long long long  long long long long long  long long long long long  long long long long long  long long long long long  long long long long long  long long long long long</div>
      <div class="child">I'm short</div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>normal</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>normal</td>
 <td>normal</td>
 <td>normal</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When `toggle text` is clicked in the above example I don't want any visual "jump" to take place, I want `parent` to always have the width and height of the longest child.

I'm looking for css solution but open to a JS one as well since a pure CSS one seems rather unlikely.

Comment: Could you please make a snippet or jsfiddle, and include the rest of the table HTML, thanks

Comment: Yes! I've just added  one :)

Comment: Jump..?  what is mean..?

Comment: Would something like this work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/7qL3mnsr/2/  -- i've replaced table with `flexbox`

Comment: No I'm afraid it has to be a table. Only the HTML inside `td` can be changed.

Answer (score 3):

If you can, you can replace `display` with alternative css properties which will simply hide the text.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.parent .child').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
table {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.child.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>toggle text</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>normal</td>
    <td>
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="child hidden">I'm long long long long long</div>
        <div class="child">I'm short</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>normal</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry I just realised that your solution is not correct. `parent` ends up getting the width of the 1st `child` + the width of the 2nd `child`.I only want `parent` to get the width (and height) of the longest child. Otherwise I end up with a `parent` that has a width much greater than necessary which is noticable when the shortest child is visible.